# How can i create an object from this single string i've split?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

im trying to make a report about supplies used by connecting to the technical service database and filtering supply audits, inside audits what i care about is ActionNotes which is a single long string formatted like this:

```
New Supplie Mobile added: /n Id: 1/n Name: Bateria /n Stock. 0/n Minimum Stock: 10/n IdSquad: 1/n IdSupplie: 1/n
```

I've managed to write this code which creates an array of strings after splitting and filtering the values that i don't need and comes out something like this:

```
private void ImportarServicioTecnico()
    {
        var auditList = db3.Audit.ToList();

        var suppliesList = (from t in auditList where t.ActionNotes.ToLower().Contains("new supplie mobile added") select t).ToList();

        foreach (var i in suppliesList)
        {
            InsumosST o = new InsumosST();
            
            var note = i.ActionNotes;
            Debug.WriteLine("Audit ID: " + i.Id.ToString() + " Date: " + i.AuditDate);

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(note, "/n");
            foreach (var l in lines)
            {
                var checkstring = l.ToLower();
                string actual = l;

                if (checkstring.Contains("new supplie mobile added") || checkstring.Contains("description:")) {continue;}

                if (checkstring.Contains("stock."))
                {
                    int pos2 = actual.IndexOf(".");
                    Debug.WriteLine(actual.Substring(pos2 + 1));
                    continue;
                }

                int pos = actual.IndexOf(":");
                Debug.WriteLine(actual.Substring(pos + 1));
       
            }
        }
    }
```

> Audit ID: 21 Date: 15-11-2021 10:43:59
> 1 Bateria 0 1 0 1 1

The question being is: is it possible to create an object from my db model with this code?
This is my model:

```
public partial class InsumosST
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string supply { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> entrydate { get; set; }
    public string squad { get; set; }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: What is preventing you from instantiating a new instance of `InsumosST` and then assigning the values you parse in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: the fact that i get just one value for each loop for "lines", so if i create a new instance i would only assign one value to the object

Answer (score 0):

Sure.. Let's have some dictionary of delegates that assign values to the properties of InsumosST, split the line on `/n` then again on `:` to get an id and value, look for the id in the dictionary and if it;s there, call the delegate passing the value

```
private void ImportarServicioTecnico()
{
    var auditList = db3.Audit.ToList();

    var suppliesList = (from t in auditList where t.ActionNotes.ToLower().Contains("new supplie mobile added") select t).ToList();


    //make a dictionary of the string we look for and the "method" to execute if we find that string
    //the methods are one-liners that set the appropriate value on the object
    var d = new Dictionary<string, Action<string, InsumosST>();
    d["id"] = (v, i) => i.id = int.TryParse(v, out int z) ? z : SOME_DEFAULT_ID_HERE; 
    d["idsupplie"] = (v, i) => i.supply = v;
    d["idsquad"] = (v, i) => i.squad = v;


    foreach (var i in suppliesList)
    {
        var o = new InsumosST();

        var bits = i.ActionNotes.Split("/n");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var bits = line.Split(new[]{':','.'}, 2);  //line is e.g. "idsupplie: 1"
            if(bits.Length < 2) continue;        //if we don't have an id and value

            var id = bits[0].ToLower();          //e.g. "idsupplie"
            var val = bits[1].Trim();            //e.g. "1"

            if(d.TryGetValue(id, out var m))     //if we know this id, e.g. "id", "idsupplie", "idsquad"
              m(val, o);                         //call the delegate; it will assign val to the right property of o
   
        }

        context.InsumosSts.Add(o);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I suppose the hardest thing to "get" about this is if you're not really used to delegates; you've used them (conceptually `where t.ActionNotes.ToLower().Contains("new supplie mobile added")` is such a thing => it's a method that produces a `bool` from some input value determined by `from`) but it doesn't mean you'd be familiar with them.

Simply put, delegates are a way of storing *method code* in a variable just like we store data. You can assign a method to a variable, and then execute the variable to run the code:

```
var someMethod = () => Debug.WriteLine("hello");
someMethod(); //prints hello
```

You can make them take parameters:

```
var someMethod = (string s) => Debug.WriteLine(s);
someMethod("hello"); //prints hello
```

So all we did here was make up a bunch of methods that assign props to a passed-in InsumosSt

```
var x = (InsumosST i, string v) => i.idsupplie = v;
x(someInsumosObject, "hello"); //assigns "hello" to someInsumosObject.idsupplie property
```

It means to support more properties, you just add them to the InsumosST and
write a dictionary entry that assigns them:

```
public partial class InsumosST
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string supply { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> entrydate { get; set; }
    public string squad { get; set; }

    //new!
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

```
d["name"] = (v, i) => i.Name = v;
```